# override colors.xml or strings.xml in cordova project

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have build ant android library, which can be used in cordova projects(I have build custom wrapper and created cordova plugin). Everything works fine, except I can't find an option **for overriding colors.xml and strings xml files**. In regular android app, user can override my library colors by declaring names of colors in his own **colors.xml file and assigning particular colors**... How can I do that in cordova plugin? It would not make sense to create additional methods and providing color code via custom methods.